# How to remove validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with validations defined, I want to monkey patch the model and remove these validations, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://casperfabricius.com/site/2008/12/06/removing-rails-validations-with-metaprogramming/) seems to explain it quite well. Too long to excerpt here.

Comment: That link is now dead, unfortunately. Via archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20150928022211/http://casperfabricius.com/site/2008/12/06/removing-rails-validations-with-metaprogramming/